# Ubuntu Touch - USB Wifi Dongle

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch, hardware, ifconfig, dongle

I'm running OTA 12 on a bq Aquaris M10 and I wish to use a USB Wifi dongle (Realtek 8188 series). I connected the dongle via an OTG cable and attempted to use `ifconfig` to configure the device; however, it doesn't appear to be recognized. Is it possible to use this device on Ubuntu Touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is very huge obstacle: drivers are missing.

1. It is not only this dongle, UT team have left out most of wifi dongle drivers, look to kernel configuration for bq M10 (The ubuntu one):

https://git.launchpad.net/~phablet-team/avila/+git/kernel-3.10/tree/arch/arm64/configs/bq_aquaris_m10_ubuntu_defconfig?h=ubuntu

2. Notice that `RTL8192` that is non existing in the kconfig (yes, 8188 uses 8192 drivers) because they were merged to mainline only at linux 4.4 or RTL8188EU driver at linux 3.12 if you are going to use the wifi in the europe:

http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/RTL8192CU.html

http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/R8188EU.html

3. Any usb wifi dongle will need kernel recompiling with enabling the dongle drivers in configuration files.
4. This dongle, if it really is needed this particular and the only available one -- the drivers could be ported back (backporting stuff in kernel is really messy, and time consuming). I would start from examining how did bluetooth stack were backported by ubuntu touch from 4.2 down to 3.10